# Deleting Kernel Image to Free Space for Upgrade

Tags: partitioning, upgrade, kernel, 22.04

I have deleted all of the old kernels (most of which were on another partition), ran `sudo apt-get autoremove` but still short on space on the partition to upgrade to 22.04 from 20.04. Below are the kernels left when running `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`

```
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic 5.15.0-43.46~20.04.1 amd64 Signed kernel image generic<br>
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic 5.15.0-46.49~20.04.1 amd64 Signed kernel image generic<br>
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 5.15.0.46.49~20.04.16 amd64 Generic Linux kernel image<br>
```

Would it be safe to remove the `5.15.0-43-generic` kernel image? For some reason I'm worried about that one despite being an older kernel. I don't have a safe way to resize the partition which is usually bad anyway. I only need 30MB more space to upgrade. Or should I just start clean (not preferred)?

Comment: Do you have the lack of space on your / partition? If so remove/uninstall a large program ( save the data you need for example gamescores ). To repartition you also need space.

Answer (score 2):

If your system boots into the newer -46 kernel, and your hardware works properly, then you can safely use apt to uninstall the older -43 kernel.

- Ubuntu automatically retains the older kernel is retained as a fallback: If your system fails to boot or encounters kernel-related problems, you have a good older kernel to fall back upon. Once you know that your new kernel works properly, you don't really need the fallback anymore.

However, the same problem is likely to re-occur with future kernels (they keep getting bigger) so eventually you will need to re-partition to make your /boot a bit larger.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot remove that kernel. It seems that it is dependent and the system says it will reinstall it with an added 328Kb. The main issue is getting space on the partition so I guess my only choice is to re-partition it. Ultimately start clean.

Comment: You can remove a large program you don't use at the moment. You will keep running into this problem though.

Comment: @JoepieEs historically, folks with this problem usually have a separate /boot partition. You're right that we didn't check *which* partition is full, and that failure to check might bite us.

Comment: You also need space to repartition. So removing a large program seems to me the best option at this moment.

Comment: @user535733 It seems to me OP is talking about the / partition. Otherwise updating would not be a problem.

Comment: @JoepieEs maybe...maybe not. We don't know. The OP has not provided that information. Feel free to comment on the question and ask for it. Then we will know if this answer applies to their situation or not.

Comment: In order to upgrade to 22.04 I need to free up about 35Mb space on the /boot partition which is a total of 767Mb. It tells me that the upgrade has aborted whenever I try. I have deleted all the old kernels. The other recommendation is to change the COMPRESS setting to COMPRESS=xz in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`. Unfortunately, I can't find anywhere or anyone to tell me how this is done. I can't even find the file on my computer. If anyone can share a step by step on this process, then I might be able to move forward.

Comment: Your original question was "*Is XYZ safe?*" Now you are asking a different question "*How do I accomplish ABC?*" A different question should be in a different Question.